# How do I catch changes in state from Firebase Auth?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, exception, angularfire2

I am using Angular 2 with angularfire library. I am having trouble catching changes in the user's state.

First) Logging in works fine. I see the user come through to my subscribe function and all is dandy.

However, When I disable that user on the Firebase console...The user state has changed. Why am I not seeing that change in state come through in my app component?

I would like to captures errors of different types, and handle them according to the error code. To do this, I created a service here:

```
@Injectable()
export class CZAuthService {

    constructor(private af: AngularFire){ }

    getAuthState() : Observable<FirebaseAuthState>{
        return this.af.auth.catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            return this.af.auth;
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to catch exceptions here in this catch operator, and then return the stream to maintain connection to the stream.

Then in my root app component, I am subscribing to this stream and handling when the user is signed in:

```
this.auth.getAuthState().subscribe((user)=>{
     console.log(user);
     if(user != null){
       this._store.dispatch(new UserLogInSuccessAction(user))
     }
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the change in state is not reflected in your component. Are you sure the Firebase JS API emits a change in state event when you disable a user in the console? If yes, it could be that AngularFire2 is not watching that event. Anyways, just wanted to mention your `catch()` could be rewritten to `this.af.auth.catch((error, caught)=>{ console.log(error); return caught; })`, `caught` being the original observable.

Comment: @AngularFrance You're right! thanks.